# c: reading/writing hashtable to file

Tags: c, file, struct, io

I am trying to write a hashtable to file in C using fwrite and read it in using fread.
I have this struct:

```
struct table {
    struct person *person_table[SIZE];
};
static struct table hashtable;
```

When I use fread, I have

```
    fread(&hashtable, sizeof(struct table), 1, file)
```

and fwrite:

```
    fwrite(&hashtable, sizeof(struct table), 1, file)
```

However, I'm not able to correctly access data after reads and writes.
What is the problem?

Comment: You cannot write raw pointer values to a file and expect them to point to the same thing when you read them back in the next time.  Every process runs in a separate virtual address space, and aside from the unpredictability of the addresses of heap allocations, things like ASLR make even a perfectly deterministic program run with different address spaces every time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't write the data of the hashtable to the file. Instead you write the addresses contained in the pointers to the `struct person` elements, which are invalid after the deserialization.

You need to write the data to file as well (pseudo-code, assuming `struct person` contains no further pointers):

```
for (person_pointer in person_table) {
  fwrite(person_pointer, sizeof(person), 1, file);
}
```